# Flatten an array of strings in Ruby

Tags: ruby

What's the best idiomatic (cleanest) way to convert an array of strings into a string, while keeping the enclosing quotes for each elements.
In other words, from this:

```
a = ["file 1.txt", "file 2.txt", "file 3.txt"]
```

I'd need to get this

```
"'file 1.txt' 'file 2.txt' 'file 3.txt'"
```

Single and double quotes could be interchanged here.
The best ways I know of is by using map and inject/reduce.

eg:     `a.map{|dir| "'" + dir + "'"}.join(' ')`
eg2:     `a.reduce("'"){|acc, dir| acc += dir+"' "}`

Performance could be improved by avoiding temp string creation (+ operator). That's not my main question though. Is there a cleaner more concise way to achieve the same result?

Comment: Do you need to escape quotes inside array members?

Comment: No, only to keep the beginning and end quotes as shown above for the array. I realise that the quotes shown are not in the strings themselves and that's why they are stripped when doing only a join on the array.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Shorter doesn't always mean simpler. Your first example was succinct, readable, and easily changeable, without being unnecessarily complex.

```
a.map { |s| "'#{s}'" }.join(' ')
```

Answer (score 14):

Try out

```
"'#{a.join("' '")}'"
```

Or if golfing

```
?'+a*"' '"+?'
```

Comment: All those quotes are finicky but you've got the best answer so far.

Comment: I'm not saying this is bad, but it doesn't exactly read naturally either. It's the sort of thing that will make even an experienced Rubyist go "Huh?" at first glance.

Comment: Interesting golf putt!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
"'" + a.join("' '") + "'"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"'"+a*"' '"+"'"
```

or

```
"'#{a*"' '"}'"
```

or

```
a.to_s[1...-1].gsub /",?/,"'"
```